# Mapping a JSON array with knockout.js mapping plugin & and view rendering not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm having a problem mapping a JSON array generated by .NET `JavaScriptSerializer`, to knockout.js. The array is generated like this (shortened for ease):

```
OrderProposalFacade[] proposals = new OrderProposalFacade[order.OrderProposals.Count];

foreach (OrderProposal proposal in order.OrderProposals)
{
    proposals[i++] = new OrderProposalFacade(proposal);
}

ViewBag.OrderProposals = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(proposals);
```

The generated JSON string is something like this:

```
[{ "ProposalId":1,"ProgrammedWeek":null,
   "ProposalValue":120,"ProposalValueCorrected":130,
   "ProposalDateSent":"01-12-2011","ProposalDateCorrected":"01-12-2011",
   "ServiceId":1,"ServiceDescriptiveId":"OS001","ProposalState":2
 },
 {//another similar object}
]
```

On the ASP.NET MVC view I do this in order to bind the array:

```
var initialData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(<%: new HtmlString(ViewBag.OrderProposals as string) %>);
var viewModel = {
    proposals: ko.observableArray(initialData),
    //some methods; removed to ease reading
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**The problem:** the `proposals` array is supposed to be rendered by a knockout.js template, but nothing is rendered. Using Firebug I don't see any objects on the `initialData` array, so I presume there is an error while initializing it and, therefore, `proposals`. The binding to the template is like this:

```
<div id="service-orders" data-bind='template: { name: "proposal-template", foreach: proposals }' style="margin:0 -.7em 0 -0.5em;"></div>
```

If I remove `ko.mapping.fromJSON()` everything works fine, i.e., the template is rendered with the values on the `proposals` array. **But** another problem arises when I update a value of an object on the `initialData` array. On my understanding if I update an observable property, the template is rendered again (therefore the knockout.js mapping), but without mapping all properties it won't happen, right?

**In short**, I need to map all the properties on the `initialData` array in order to make them observable to update my view when I change a value of one of it's objects, but it isn't working.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: for a start why are you using `HtmlString`? simple `<%:ViewBag.OrderProposals %>` should suffice. Secondly, changing value of any item in the `observableArray` will not render the template again. `observableArray` only observes the addition/deletion in the array and not modifications in it's individual items.

Comment: @nEEbz: ok, the assumption I made was wrong. How can I detect a change? shall I use updateFromJS?

Comment: Isn't  `ko.mapping.fromJSON(<%: PROPOSAL STUFF %>);` completely statically rendered/generated inline by ASP?  In other words, ko.mapping.fromJSON isn't needed at 'compile' time, i.e. you only need it if you were populating `intialdata` dynamically at runtime.

Comment: you probably shouldn't use the : in there either, but stick to = as you don't want it to be escaped, the serialiser has already done it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally solved it! The final Javascript is like this:

```
var initialData = <%: new HtmlString(ViewBag.OrderProposals as string) %>;
var viewModel = {
    proposals: ko.observableArray(),
    //some methods; removed to ease reading
};

viewModel.proposals = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The 2 changes I made:

- instead of `ko.mapping.fromJSON(initialData)` I call `ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData)`. Not shure, but I it seems that `.fromJSON()` has some problem mapping the array I putted on the question;
- the `.fromJS()` method is invoked after the `viewModel` creation.

Comment: I think fromJSON don't work because when you create your javascript string from an HtmlString, you receive a string without encoding and this is considered as a valid Javascript object but not a valid JSON. To have a valid JSON object, you will need to not use the HtmlString but in this case, you will have a couple of problems with some invalids characaters to parse. I think the only reason to use fromJSON is when you make an ajax call that returns a valid JSON stream from the server. Another way could be to convert your initialData to JSON.